# IShellFolder.EnumObjects - Async on windows explorer

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, explorer, shell-extensions

I am implemented [Shell Namespace Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in my application

One of the interface that I implement was IShellFolder,and IShellFolder2
Everything works fine excep when explorer call to EnumObjects I want to display a progress bar on explorer in an async way.
Today when I return to explorer IEnumIDList in EnumObjects function,explorer call to IEnumIDList.Next. in that function my code do massive operation that can take ~20 seconds, in that time explorer stuck and it not responsive.
What I see that If I return to explorer ~200 items and than do the massive operations explorer will display the progress bar and will be responsive.

Any one know how to force explorer to be responsive and to display the progress bar without returning dummy items?

Comment: Cannot confirm the problem you have. In my NSE IEnumIDList is created and used always in separate thread and UI is always responsive. What the OS version do you use?

Comment: I am using windows 7 x64 .  Did you try to stuck the Next function and move the current widows of explorer with the mouse?

Comment: I am using Win7 x64 too. And I can move and resize Explorer window during long Next execution.

Comment: @Beno: Windows Explorer uses [`IShellFolderViewCB::MessageSFVCB()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774968.aspx) to communicate with `IShellView`, and one of the defined messages is [`SFVM_BACKGROUNDENUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774205.aspx): "*Allows the callback object to request enumeration on a background thread.*".

Comment: Thanks, thats a really good information. I will try to look on potential problems in my code

Comment: Windows 7 never send SFVM_BACKGROUNDENUM and always uses separate thread.

Comment: Do you have any resource protected with critical section or mutex used by UI thread and Enum thread at the same time?

Comment: Hi Denis, I had found the problem, it was somthing like you say. The main thread ask for icons for the files. that action was synchrony , once I release that call it works, Thanks:)

Comment: Denis can you please write it as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 always uses separate thread for item enumeration. In your case resource lock is reason of UI freezing.

Comment: Hi Denis, I had found the problem, it was somthing like you say. The main thread ask for icons for the files. that action was synchrony , once I release that call it works, Thanks:)